# How to check if it's a certain time like e.g. 2:00pm

Tags: python, datetime

I'm making an automation with selenium and PyAutoGui that sends an email to my friends at exactly 2:00pm, but I don't understand what format the

> datetime.datetime.now()

returns in, and how to figure out when its 2:00pm(what I mean by format is what this returns in)
can someone help me?

Comment: [`now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) returns a `datatime` object and you can check the values of its attributes: e.g. `dt.hour`.

Comment: Can you show us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far, and where *specifically* in that attempt you're getting stuck? See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean, but you can convert datetime to a string and check if it's 2pm like this:

```
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
if time == '14:00:00':
    print("It's 2pm")
else:
    print(f"It's {time}, that's not 2pm")
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

dates are converted to iso 8601 strings

```
import datetime
#https://strftime.org/
d=datetime.datetime.now()
print(d.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
print(d.strftime("%H:%m %p"))
match=d.strftime("%H:%m %p")=="14:00 PM"
print(match)
```